# How to convert GCP console to API command?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I would like to know the API commands used when I use the GCP console.

For example, below is a screenshot of the GCP console to create a VM instance.

How to see what the

```
gcloud compute instances create VM_NAME [--image IMAGE | --image-family IMAGE_FAMILY] --image-project IMAGE_PROJECT --machine-type=
```

statement would be if the "CREATE" button is pressed on the console?

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for the equivalent CLI command? If that's the case, at the bottom, next to the create and cancel button, there is one called "equivalent command line".

Comment: kornshell93 Thank you.  This is the answer. I will post it as such unless you do.

Comment: @JDOaktown That is the correct answer for this one case. For the other thousand GCP commands, there are other techniques available. This question has been asked and answered a few times.

Comment: John Hanley - I've looked before I posted this & couldn't find anything.  Any links would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was much easier than I thought.  Thank you kornshell93.

At the bottom of the GCP console, next to the create and cancel button, there is a button called

```
equivalent command line
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the accepted solution if you use any gcloud command you can get the equivalent rest api command adding the flag `--log-http`